# How to create unique index where column order is not taken into account (set?)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two columns in a table: `Object1` and `Object2`.
I would like to make pair (`Object1`, `Object2`) unique in a way that it wont allow to insert two rows like this:

```
Object1 = 1, Object2 = 2
Object1 = 2, Object2 = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an index on an expression, in this case `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
create unique index idx_obj1_obj2 on table(least(Object1, Object2), greatest(Object1, Object2));
```

Note:  there is one slight weirdness if the columns allow `NULL` values.  In that case, the same value would only be allowed once, regardless of the column it is in.  This can be fixed with a more complicated expression, if it is actually a problem.

Comment: Wow thats very clever :), thanks. My columns don't allow NULLs so this is what I was looking for.